# fadeToggle() with pure javascript (no jQuery)

Tags: javascript

I want to know how to fadeToggle() an element with pure javascript.

So for example I want this jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("div").fadeToggle("slow"); 
  });
});
```

to be converted to javascript code

Comment: see `fadeToggle` function documentation.

Comment: This is not a "I want you to do my work" place... Check the source from [jQuery](https://github.com/jquery/jquery)

Comment: Have you tried something so far? If not try and post a new question along with code when you're stuck

Comment: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#fade_in might help

Comment: I dont want anynone to do my "work" I just wanted to know about it, thats why i wrote "example"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to find out how it works, is look at the [source](http://robflaherty.github.io/jquery-annotated-source/docs/13-effects.html#section-27)

It actually uses the [animate](http://robflaherty.github.io/jquery-annotated-source/docs/13-effects.html#section-11) function

Here is the similar [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/7315/fade-in-and-fade-out-in-pure-javascript)